# How to create viewmodel ,controller & view to join many to many table in asp.net mvc Entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many, viewmodel, join

**I want to join & display  "ProductId,Quantity,UnitPrice,Discount & Total" columns from tblOrder ,tblCustomer ,tblProduct tables where OrderNo= givenId .**

OrderNo is given through a textbox.[This is how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAAPC.png)

[DataBase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6m5Rb.png)

**Order Table**

```
public partial class tblOrder
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public tblOrder()
    {
        this.tblProducts = new HashSet<tblProduct>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int OrderNo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Quantity { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Discount { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Total { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> SubTotal { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> DiscountTotal { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Tax { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> NetTotal { get; set; }
    public int CustomerCode { get; set; }

    public virtual tblCustomer tblCustomer { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<tblProduct> tblProducts { get; set; }
}
```

**Product Table**

```
public partial class tblProduct
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public tblProduct()
    {
        this.tblOrders = new HashSet<tblOrder>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string UnitPrice { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<tblOrder> tblOrders { get; set; }
}
```

**Customer Table**

```
public partial class tblCustomer
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public tblCustomer()
    {
        this.tblOrders = new HashSet<tblOrder>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int CustomerCode { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<tblOrder> tblOrders { get; set; }
}
```

**This is the ViewModel I created**

```
public class OrderCustomerProductViewModel
{
    public OrderCustomerProductViewModel() { }
    public OrderCustomerProductViewModel(tblOrder orderow, tblCustomer customerow, tblProduct productrow)
    {
        OrderNo = orderow.OrderNo;
        CustomerName = customerow.CustomerName;
        ProductId = productrow.ProductId;
        Quantity = orderow.Quantity;
        UnitPrice = productrow.UnitPrice;
        Discount = orderow.Discount;
        Total = orderow.Total;
    }

    public int OrderNo { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Quantity { get; set; }
    public string UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Discount { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Total { get; set; }
}
```

**I tried to send all the data to view using a list as follows , but there were some errors encountered .
It says**

> ICollection  doesn't contain a definition for ProductId and UnitPrice

**Please help me to fix this error. Thanks in advance**

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    var results = (db.tblOrders.Where(l => l.OrderNo == id).Include(c => c.tblCustomer).Include(p => p.tblProducts)
          .Select(v => new OrderCustomerProductViewModel
              {                        
                  CustomerName = v.tblCustomer.CustomerName,
                  ProductId = v.tblProducts.ProductId,
                  Quantity = v.Quantity,
                  UnitPrice = v.tblProducts.UnitPrice,
                  Discount  = v.Discount,
                  Total = v.Total,
        })).ToList();

    return View(results);
}
```

[!  I tried as [Jaggan_j] said but it doesn't work. [Jaggan_j] Please help me[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmBpP.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmBpP.png)

Comment: The Product and Order table are having a many to many relationship, you can join them with a linking table

Comment: I can't use linking table to join many to many table since Entity framework eliminates linking table.

Answer (score 1):

ProductId and UnitPrice are attributes of a single Product and not of a collection of Products, which is causing the error. So you have to get all Products in an Order by returning a list of Products. You can add a list of Product to the view model:

```
List<tblProduct> tblProductList { get; set; }
```

and get all the corresponding Products in an order like:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
   var results = (db.tblOrders.Where(l => l.OrderNo == id).Include(c => c.tblCustomer)
                  .Include(p => p.tblProducts)
                  .Select(v => new OrderCustomerProductViewModel
                  {                        
                      tblProductList = v.tblProducts.ToList(),
                      --rest of your select--
                  })).ToList();

   return View(results);
}
```

Then in the View, you just have to iterate through tblProductList to display each product's Id and Unit Price.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but still i'm struggling with this code ,  above I have uploaded an image of the error encountered . Please check it and help me . It will be a big help for me.

Comment: @Sameera Udakumbura - use another loop within your first loop to iterate through tblProductList like `@foreach(var product in item.tblProductList) { @Html.DisplayFor(model => product.UnitPrice) }`